# Vim unable to find Python27.dll on startup but I'm on Python3.11

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, vim

I'm looking to get comfortable with vim and I set up my system according to these two tutorials.

https://realpython.com/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/
https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/wiki/Vundle-for-Windows

I have Vim in program files (x86) and vundle in \vimfiles\bundle.

My _vimrc script looks like this:

```
filetype off
set shellslash
set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin('C:/Users/mshen/vimfiles/bundle')
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

set splitbelow
set splitright
"split navigations
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>

" Enable folding
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99

" Enable folding with the spacebar
nnoremap <space> za

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set expandtab
    \ set autoindent
    \ set fileformat=unix

au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/

py << EOF
import os
import sys
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
  project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
  activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir, 'bin/activate_this.py')
  execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
EOF

let python_highlight_all=1
syntax on

call togglebg#map("<F5>")

let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.pyc$', '\~$'] "ignore files in NERDTree

set nu

set clipboard=unnamed
set editing-mode vi

"default _vimrc below 
"...
```

When I try to run Vim (from shortcut or powershell $vim), it gives me the following error:

[Vim startup error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKs4e.png)

Why is this thing looking for python27?

Thanks!

I know the plugins are properly installed. I know that the line numbering works. I'm not familiar with vim enough to know how to access the other plugins.

My python is 64 bit, but I don't think 32 vs 64 mismatch is causing the error because either way, I don't have python27 and don't know why vim wants it instead of the latest release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change your vimrc to use `:python3` and `:py3` instead of `:python` and `:py`.

For example, in this line:

```
py << EOF
import os
...
```

Update that to

```
py3 << EOF
import os
...
```

The "VIM and Python – A Match Made in Heaven" is a great article, but it's also kinda outdated as it was last updated at 2018-06-01.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, does this include file extensions?

Comment: Ok hmm, its telling me it can't find python36, does this mean I should revert my python to 3.6 from 3.11?

Comment: Vim is always linked with a specific version of Python, so you need to install the exact Python version that Vim expects, which must be installed separately. However, you must have installed a very ancient version of Vim; the earliest [Vim 9 official Windows Installer](https://www.vim.org/download.php) should require at least Python 3.10 and the more recent versions would require Python 3.11. That your Vim build expects a 3.6 indicates that you must be on a Vim 8.0 or 8.1 or something of that vintage.

Comment: Unless you somehow need to use a very old plugin that doesn't work with the latest Vim and Python version, you should uninstall your Vim and reinstall the latest version of Vim from the official website.